# how to add Row Span in dynamic Json Table React JS and table cell data comparison

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, reactjs

the JSON data which i get from back-end has dynamic keys and value. the below data is one of the example method data which i need to convert the first column value as rowSpan that is my requirement. is this possible for rowspan and comparing the numeric value of the cell data and add icon for it..? please give me solution

```
data= [
{carrier: "Emirates", range: "min", "Jul 29": 1275, "Jul 30": 1325},
{carrier: "Emirates",  range: "med", "Jul 29": 1275, "Jul 30": 1338},
{carrier: "Emirates",  range: "max", "Jul 29": 1275, "Jul 30": 1375},
{carrier: "rehlat",  range: "min", "Jul 29": 1138, "Jul 30": 1306},
{carrier: "rehlat",  range: "med", "Jul 29": 1198, "Jul 30": 1330},
{carrier: "rehlat", range: "max", "Jul 29": 1258, "Jul 30": 1354}]
```

the code which i'm using for it is given below

```
const RenderRow = (props) =>{
 return props.keys.map((key, index)=>{
 return <td>{props.data[key]}</td>
 })
}


class Mycomponent extends Component {
 
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.getHeader = this.getHeader.bind(this);
 this.getRowsData = this.getRowsData.bind(this);
 this.getKeys = this.getKeys.bind(this);
 }
 
 getKeys = function(){
    return Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
 }
 
 getHeader = function(){
    var keys = this.getKeys();
 return keys.map((key, index)=>{
 return <th key={key}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
 })
 }
 
 getRowsData = function(){
  var items = this.props.data;
 var keys = this.getKeys();
 return items.map((row, index)=>{
 return <tr key={index}><RenderRow key={index} data={row} keys={keys}/></tr>
 })
 }
 
 render() {
 return (
 <div>
 <table>
 <thead>
 <tr>{this.getHeader()}</tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 {this.getRowsData()}
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 
 );
 }
}
```

my Output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMrMZ.jpg)

expected output  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4mAY.jpg)

code added in codesandbox
[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-vaughan-itkdj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: can you post a codesandbox in order for us to work on it and help you?

Comment: also the json posted is not valid one.

Comment: i've not worked in codebox before

Comment: it's easy. it has ready templates for react projects. also fix your json.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-vaughan-itkdj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @apostolos i've added in codesandbox too

Comment: @Apostolos please get me the solution as soon as possible

Comment: i'm working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it can take lot of improvement but as a start try this codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-gauss-ffs5d

```
   let keys = this.state.data.reduce(function(a, e) {
      let estKey = e["carrier"];
      (a[estKey] ? a[estKey] : (a[estKey] = null || [])).push(e);
      return a;
    }, {});
```

The whole idea is to group by your desired property and then, after you know how many items you have based on your property, you can loop and render equivalent rows and tds.

```
return Object.keys(keys).map((key, index) => {
  return keys[key].map((obj, index2) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index} style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "red" }}>
        <RenderRow
          key={index2}
          idx={index2}
          data={obj}
          keys={key}
          rows={keys[key].length}
        />
      </tr>
    );
  });
});
```

So you take all the keys that you grouped by your array and then you apply a `map` function.
For each key, you take the equivalent list (that's what the `reduce` function does) and loop through that list.
Each list should create `list.length` rows but only the first row should have the `<td>` with the `rowSpan` attribute.

The key here also is to know that you need to render only 1 time the `td` with `rownSpan` property, so you need to check the `index` while `map`-ing.

Comment: thanks a lot @Apostolos ... is there any possible for cell comparison and render the icon with the value

Comment: like the image i've posted in the quesion

Comment: it gets a little bit trickier now. for example, how should you calculate the icon for the first column? for the other 2 you can "play" with indexes and compare their values

Comment: you can compare values like this but since not all the columns are number, it can be tricy. but here is a hint `props.data[index - 1] > props.data[index]  ? "down" : "up"`